# How to add the txt file name ahead of each line ? (with notepad++, or grep command, or ..)

Tags: regex, grep, notepad++

I have different text files dispatched into several folders, like this :

- FolderA

  - file1.txt
  - file2.txt
  - file3.txt
- FolderB

  - file10.txt
  - file14.txt
- ...

Each line of the text files gives an information like "Line of informations".

I would like to add to each line of each file, the name of its folder and the name of the file. So that the result inside each file would be :

```
FolderA file1 "line of informations"
FolderA file1 "line of informations"
...
```

I haven't found a way to do this with notepad++ regular expressions (or any other tool) ... and I'm not really used to grep command ...

Is there a way to do this with notepad++, another tool or grep commmand in Cygwin ?

Thanks in advance !
Clem

Comment: you should better explain the content of your text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you can use grep. As manpage says,

> -H, --with-filename
>
> Print the file name for each match.  This is the default when there is more than one file to search.

I've checked this on my machine: if you specify relative path

```
./*.txt
```

it will print out the relative names, but if you specify full path

```
/some/path/*.txt
```

it will print full path to files.

So, you can grep output of the first grep and do whatever you want with data.

Comment: Thank you Ivan ! Could you give me some advices on how to re-use the result then ? (... as far as I'm clearly not used to linux commands..)

Comment: @clem You can use something like [this](http://pastebin.com/NBW96cep) to add file path and filename to each line of each .txt file in any subderictory. Be careful, I've made it for like 10-20 minutes, so, it can be buggy. But still, it will be good as reference, IMO.